# Using 3to2 in Python, get "python: can't open file '3to2': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have installed 3to2-1.1.1 on my system (found [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/3to2/1.1.1)),
cd'd to the directory of my test file (a simple "Hello, world!" program written in 3 syntax) Typed into my command prompt:

```
python 3to2 HelloWorld.py
```

With the following output:

```
python: can't open file '3to2': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I attempted to change the directory name/path, but after looking over [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723547/received-cant-find-main-module-in-packagename-with-python-package) post, I'm convinced it may be a dependency issue?

I have raised an issue on the creator's repo, and searched endlessly on the interwebs, but seem to be the only person in the world experiencing this issue.

I have tried uninstalling and re-installing just...so many ways. Any and all help appreciated - even if you just tell me it's operator error.

Extra notes:

- I am running Python 2.7 (but also tried installing and running this with 3)
- I am using a Windows cmd

Comment: Have you tried passing the complete path of 3to2 to Python? Like this: `python \path\to\3to2 HelloWorld.py`

Comment: @KevinGuan and Quirk, I have even tried moving my file into the 3to2 folder, i.e. - 
`C:\Users\username\3to2-1.1.1>python 3to2  -w HelloWorld.py`
To no avail... 
Also installed in various ways (build, setup install, pip, etc).

Edit - markdown formatting

Comment: Okay, this may sound silly, but does the file `3to2` even exist? Additionally you could try renaming `3to2` to `3to2.py` and then running. You are basically getting an ENOENT error (I/O error). That would either mean a problem with PYTHONPATH, PATH or the file.

Answer (score 1):

Windows cannot take care of shebangs. The default association in Windows is through file extensions. However, the file `3to2` does not come with a `.py` extension (only a shebang). As a result Windows is usually unable to determine what to do with the file.

OP discussed the following use cases:

- `python 3to2 <arg-file>`. This doesn't work for me in a `pip` install. Python throws an internal ENOENT (I/O) error. This use case is discarded.
- `3to2 <arg-file>`. Doesn't work either. This is because Windows doesn't know how to execute this file. Funnily enough Windows cannot find the file even though its location is in the system `PATH`. Calling `where` gives negative results. Windows is not able to handle filenames without extensions, somehow.
- Rename `3to2` to `3to2.py` (in `%PYTHON_INSTALL_DIRECTORY%\Scripts\`) since it really is a python source file. Python on Windows is set up to handle `.py` file by default. The location of the file is in the system `PATH`. Try calling `3to2.py <arg-file>`. **This works!**
- Returning to the first case: After renaming, try calling `python 3to2.py <arg-file>`. Still doesn't work. Python throws an ENOENT error.

#### In conclusion, renaming the file `3to2.py` is a hack that works. The dependent programs might not work.

---

#### Don't give up just yet!

So why did calling `3to2.py` through Python fail? The answer is simple. Python only calls what you give it. When you specify a relative path, it will only look in the current working directory of the program and no more. When you give an absolute path, Python does the needful.

---

NOTES:

- I only installed the package through `pip` **only.** I did not test through any other methods.
- I tested this on a Windows 7 SP1 system. Newer versions may have better filesystem support.

Answer (score 0):

I tried install it via `pip` on my Linux, it works out-of-the-box.

However, you could just use it like `2to3`. So type `3to2 -w HelloWorld.py` in `cmd` maybe works. If `cmd` can't find the path of `3to2`, then you need to find it manually.

```
kevin@Arch ~> cat 1.py 
print('Hello')
var = input('text')


kevin@Arch ~> 3to2 1.py
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: collections
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: int
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: memoryview
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: printfunction
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: unittest
RefactoringTool: Refactored 1.py
b'--- 1.py\t(original)'
b'+++ 1.py\t(refactored)'
b'@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@'
b"-print('Hello')"
b"-var = input('text')"
b"+print u'Hello'"
b"+var = raw_input(u'text')"
RefactoringTool: Files that need to be modified:
RefactoringTool: 1.py


kevin@Arch ~> 3to2 -w 1.py
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: collections
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: int
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: memoryview
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: printfunction
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: unittest
RefactoringTool: Refactored 1.py
b'--- 1.py\t(original)'
b'+++ 1.py\t(refactored)'
b'@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@'
b"-print('Hello')"
b"-var = input('text')"
b"+print u'Hello'"
b"+var = raw_input(u'text')"
RefactoringTool: Files that were modified:
RefactoringTool: 1.py


kevin@Arch ~> cat 1.py 
print u'Hello'
var = raw_input(u'text')
kevin@Arch ~>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this seems to be the case. It doesn't appear anyone is able to replicate my issue, which is making me feel like a crazy person!

Comment: @RobotLauren: What's the error are you getting when you running `C:\Users\username\3to2-1.1.1>python 3to2 -w HelloWorld.py`?

Answer (score 0):

After installing on another system, I have not been able to replicate the issue. this makes me believe that something is wrong on my side of things. I will update here if I ever figure it out.