# Making a top level python module callable?

Tags: python

Is it possible to perform an action when a top level python *package* is called from the command line?

For example, my current structure looks like this:

```
MyApp 
    | - subdir1 
        | - pyfile.py
        | - pyfile.py
        | - pyfile.py
    | - subdir2
        | - subsubdir1
            | - pyfile.py
            | - pyfile.py
    - __init__ 
    - other.py
```

And I can do all the normal stuff. e.g. `from MyApp.subdir1 import pyfile`.

However, I'd like to allow users to call the app via its top level name from command line and have it do something

```
python MyApp [options]
```

Rather than them having to scope it to a specific module with a `main()` func

```
python /path/to/MyApp/actions/somemodule.py [options]
```

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `python -m MyApp [options]`, where your `__init__.py` contains a `if __name__ == "__main__":` block.

If you want to make that even easier for users, make it so that your `setup.py` script installs a command (e.g. `/usr/bin/MyApp`) that just contains the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
python -m MyApp $@
```

That way, they don't even have to know it's a Python program. All they have to do is call `MyApp [options]`.

Setuptools can even generate that automatically, it's called an "entry point". See this question for more details on how they work: [Explain Python entry points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774824/explain-python-entry-points)