# running a python package after compiling and uploading to pypicloud server

Tags: python, pypi

Folks,
  After building and deploying a package called `myShtuff` to a local pypicloud server, I am able to install it into a separate virtual env.

Everything seems to work, except for the path of the executable...

```
(venv)[ec2-user@ip-10-0-1-118 ~]$ pip freeze
Fabric==1.10.1
boto==2.38.0
myShtuff==0.1
ecdsa==0.13
paramiko==1.15.2
pycrypto==2.6.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

If I try running the script directly, I get:

```
(venv)[ec2-user@ip-10-0-1-118 ~]$ myShtuff
-bash: myShtuff: command not found
```

However, I can run it via:

```
(venv)[ec2-user@ip-10-0-1-118 ~]$ python /home/ec2-user/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/myShtuff/myShtuff.py
..works
```

Am I making a mistake when building the package?  Somewhere in setup.cfg or setup.py?

Thanks!!!

Comment: What's you setup.py like?

Comment: Have you tried running `myShtuff.py`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a `__main__.py` in your package, and an entry point defined in setup.py.

See [here](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) and [here](https://chriswarrick.com/blog/2014/09/15/python-apps-the-right-way-entry_points-and-scripts/) but in short, your `__main__.py` runs whatever your main functionality is when running your module using `python -m`, and setuptools can make whatever arbitrary functions you want to run as scripts. You can do either or both. Your `__main__.py` looks like:

```
from .stuff import my_main_func

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_main_func()
```

and in setup.py:

```
  entry_points={
  'console_scripts': [
      'myShtuffscript = myShtuff.stuff:my_main_func'
  ]
```

Here, `myShtuffscript` is whatever you want the executable to be called, `myShtuff` the name of your package, `stuff` the name of file in the package (`myShtuff/stuff.py`), and `my_main_func` the name of a function in that file.

Answer (score 4):

You need to define `entry_point` in your `setup.py` in order to directly execute something from the command line:

```
entry_points={
    'console_scripts': [
        'cursive = cursive.tools.cmd:cursive_command',
    ],
},
```

More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774824/explain-python-entry-points).