# How do I use setuptools or distutils to distribute a script as opposed to a Python package?

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

In the past, most tutorials that I've seen of `distutils` or `setuptools` seem geared toward distributing so-called "Python packages"; i.e., collections of closely related Python modules, which are ultimately intended to be imported together as a unit into something else.

I have something slightly different: a large command line script.  The script currently lives in a Python project with a structure that looks similar to this:

```
git_repo/
    .gitignore
    README.rst
    src/
        myscript.py
        sub_module1.py
        sub_module2.py
        sub_module3.py
    test/
        test_sub_module1.py
        test_sub_module2.py
        test_sub_module3.py
```

Inside of the `myscript.py` file, the first several lines look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sub_module1
import sub_module2
import sub_module3

# Go do a bunch of stuff...
# etc...
```

The code contained in the various submodules is mostly stuff that I couldn't imagine ever wanting to re-use in another project; those pieces are all fairly specific to the main application, `myscript.py`.  In addition, the material inside of each `submodule.py` file is also not all that closely related between one submodule and another.  Collectively, I don't think that it would be particularly natural or logical to group them together into a sub-package with its own `__init__.py` file.  In fact, the only reason I even have these submodule files in the first place is simply to help organize the main script more cleanly; doing it that way results in the top-level `myscript.py` file coming out to, say, 100 lines, rather than all piled together into a single massive 1000 line scroll.

Within my `git_repo/src` directory, I can execute this script by typing it out at the command line, e.g.:

```
./myscript.py --opt1 <value_1> --opt2 <value_2> --opt3 <value_3> ...
```

My question: since this project is a command line script and not an importable package, how should I call the `setuptools` `setup()` function in that case?  How do I select the input parameters to `setup()` in order to let it know that it should treat `myscript.py` as an executable script (meaning, for example, that it knows to do `chmod 755 myscript.py` during installation), while also making clear that the accompanying `submodule.py` files, although not scripts themselves, are nevertheless required dependencies which should be installed adjacent to `myscript.py` within the same directory?  What is the correct form of the `setup` function in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use setuptools entry points and `pip install pkg` will create a `bin/` script for you. When you do a system-wide package installation the script will go to `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`.

[About entry points](https://stackoverflow.com/a/782984/315168)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer. It sounds like you're saying: 1.) Put all of my code inside a subdirectory called ``pkg``, together with an ``__init__.py`` file, 2.) rewrite ``myscript.py`` as a function within that package, 3.) reference the ``myscript()`` function as an entry point in the call to ``setup()``, 4.) setuptools will install the package in my site_packages area and also auto-generate a script to go in ``/usr/local/bin``. That may fix the problem, but is there no way to write a ``setup.py`` file that simply works with the project structure that I already have right now?

Comment: Yes, basically I am saying 1, 2, 3, 4. This is the best practice of Python community and the recommended way to do it. For more information please refer to https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/distributing.html

Comment: O.K., thanks, I took a look at the information in the link and it seems that you are correct.