# Do I need to have a __init__ file if package consists of one file only?

Tags: python, pip, package, init, pypi

I am planning to create a Python package. However, I only have one file in my repository to be part of the package. Should I call this file `__init__`? Or can I keep the original name since I only have one file?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html “The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python _treat directories containing the file as packages_.”

Comment: Related: [How can a Python module single file be installed using pip and PyPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33431816/11082165). If you only have one file, you can just leave it as a top-level module.