# Python 3.5 on Windows: How to run this from command line?

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, importerror

I have a project structure like:

```
MyPackage
|
├──mypackage
|     |
|     ├── __init__.py
|     |
|     ├── config.py 
|     |
|     ├── data_clean
|     |   ├── __init__.py
|     |   └── f1.py
|     |
|     ├── data_transform
|     |   ├── __init__.py
|     |   └── g1.py
|     |
|     └── stat_calc
|         ├── __init__.py
|         ├── s1.py
|         └── command_line_interface.py # <- users will use this from cmd.exe
| 
├── README.txt    
|
└── setup.py
```

I need to be able to do `python path/to/command_line_interface.py arg1` but when I do this I get `ImportError: No module named 'stat_calc'`. Inside of `command_line_interface.py` I have tried putting both:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path/to/MyPackage')
```

and also:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path/to/MyPackage/mypackage')
```

and also:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path/to/MyPackage/mypackage/data_clean')
sys.path.append('path/to/MyPackage/mypackage/data_transform')
sys.path.append('path/to/MyPackage/mypackage/stat_calc')
```

but none of them worked. When I run all my stuff in my Pycharm Editor, without command line, my packages like `stat_calc` and `data_clean` import from each other using `import mypackage.data_clean.f1` syntax and that seems to work fine, but running from command line doesn't work.I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong when trying to setup command line access. All of my **init**.py files are empty.

Comment: `python -m mypackage.statcalc.command_line_interface [args]` while cwd is `MyPackage`?

Comment: `cwd` or `current working directory` would be like my `C drive` or anything else. So `cwd` could be anything, not just `MyPackage`

Comment: My method will allow you to run your code without further actions. Said working directory is necessary for proper discovery of your package. In terms of general solutions you are looking for [`entry points`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/774824/explain-python-entry-points), which will create relevant "runner" (entry point) during installation of package. Notice that after installing a package it'll be discovered in standard Python package location therefore it'll be runnable from any working dir.

Comment: Just to repeat what you said to make sure I understand, I should `cd` into `MyPackage` and then do `python -m mypackage.statcalc.command_line_interface [args]`, is that right?