# How to run a separate function not included in if __name__=="__main__" from the command line?

Tags: python, shell

I have a python file which contains the below code

**test.py**

```
def sum(a, b):
    print(a+b)

def final():
    print("Hello")
    sum(10, 9)


if __name__=="__main__":
    final()
```

Now when I run from the command line

```
python test.py
```

I get

```
Hello
19
```

Now I want to add a function `say` which will be called separately from the command line.How do I do it?So my updated code will be

```
def sum(a, b):
    print(a+b)

def say():
    print("Yes!!!")

def final():
    print("Hello")
    sum(10, 9)


if __name__=="__main__":
    final()
```

So now I want to call the function `say` seperately.I tried doing this

```
python test.py say
```

But it only outputs the previous result.How can I make this work?

Comment: `say` will appear in your arguments, so test your arguments in the script.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am sorry but I don't quite understand.Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Add a line before `final` that prints `sys.argv` and run your script with `python test.py say` and you'll see your program can detect the presence of `say` as a parameter. If it does, call `say`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start the python interpreter on the command line from the directory where your source file is. Then you can do

```
from test import say
say()
```

**Edit:**

Based on the comments above, you could check sys.argv to find if the module was called with "say":

```
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if 'say' in sys.argv:
        say()
    else:
        final()
```

sys.argv is a list with all the arguments the module was called with so if you from the command line run

```
python test.py say foo bar
```

then

```
sys.argv = ['test.py', 'say', 'foo', 'bar']
```

inside your program.

Comment: Is there any way to do it from the command line?Since I have a cron job that executes a command line query.

Comment: When the module is run from the command line, it's name will be '__main__', so as you have written your program in the question, it will call the final() function. The module will have another name only when it is imported somewhere else. I would go for @MarkSetchell's suggestion and look in sys.args, which is a list of all arguments that the module was called with from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will have to know what to do, somehow. This leaves you two alternatives:

**1. The code will decide what to do based on external information:**

a. Read a variable from the environment:

```
import os

if os.environ.get('TERM') == 'xterm-256color':
    say()
else:
    final()
```

You may set environment variables before calling the script as in:

```
# set the variable
$ export VARIABLE=VALUE

# Python will recognize it:
$ python -c "import os; print(os.environ.get('VARIABLE'))"
$ VALUE
```

b. Roll a dice:

```
from random import randint

if randint(0,6) > 3:
    say()
else:
    final()
```

**2. You will tell the code what to do:**

a. Check sys.argv (see other answers).

b. *Recommended:* Use the [argparse library](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/argparse.html) to parse commands:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--say", help="If say, then say", action="store_true")
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.say:
   say()
else:
   final()
```

Now, from the command line run: `python test.py --say`

Argparse is part of the standard python library, has excellent documentation, is easy to use and read, and (in my opinion) is very flexible.

c. For somewhat larger scripts / projects, use setuptools entrypoints:
    Details [on this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774824/explain-python-entry-points#9615473) and [this post](https://www.eflglobal.com/setuptools-entry-points/).

Comment: I think your answer would be more useful if you explained for 1a) *how* you might set the environment variable in advance of running the script, and if at 2) you explained *why* it is recommended to introduce a new dependence on `argparse`