# How to make alias for python script, similar to black?

Tags: python, python-3.x, alias, argv

I am wondering how to make an entry point to call a python script, similar to `black`.
e.g.:
`black my_script.py`

Say I have a python file called `fix_newline.py`.

Instead of calling `python fix_newline.py path/to/my_script.py` in the directory of `fix_newline.py`, I'd like to assign the name `fix_newline` to `python path/to/fix_newline.py`.

The ultimate goal is to call `fix_newline` from anywhere in my directory tree, as long as I am in the same environment (e.g. `~/.bash_profile`).

Comment: build a proper python package with a setup.py etc. ?

Comment: OK, this is the path I am looking to go (eventually want to package script). Could you point me to a useful resource?

Comment: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/ https://packaging.python.org/ etc.

Comment: I also like RealPython: https://realpython.com/pypi-publish-python-package/ and https://realpython.com/lessons/building-your-python-package/

Comment: One useful thing you can do, by the way, is run `type black`. If `black` were an alias, the `type` command will tell you that. Instead, it's an executable entry-point wrapper; _that's_ what you should be trying to create (or, rather, letting the packaging tools create on your behalf).

Comment: @irahorecka, re: the tools to use to do this job right, see [explain python entry points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774824/explain-python-entry-points)

Comment: @irahorecka, ...but no, what that creates is **not** an alias. "alias" is a specific technical term with a very limited meaning -- it refers only to places where the shell is configured to perform prefix substitution. `pip` is not an alias. `black` is not an alias.

Comment: ...and  answers should be added **as answers**, not edited into questions.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, let me change to entry point

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found a way to make an alias via packaging to PyPI as suggested by @Chris_Rands and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774824/explain-python-entry-points) provided by @CharlesDuffy:

```
setup(
    ...,
    entry_points={"console_scripts": ["realpython=reader.__main__:main"]},
)
```

The `entry_point` kwarg in `setup` function in `setup.py` should be the trick.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `path/to` to your `PATH` variable `.bash_profile`. (If you have a lot of scripts, consider installing them in a fixed location like `~/bin/`, so that you don't add a lot of unnecessary directories to your `PATH`.
2. Make sure you script is executable and has an appropriate shebang.
3. Drop the `.py` from the script name.

Comment: possible ok in the short term but this feels like a path to messy package management

Comment: You don't need full-blown package management. One option is to simply create a symlink in `~/bin/` to wherever your script lives.

Comment: (My answer was assuming the OP didn't *want* to create an actual package, but merely run a script from some working directory.)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a Bash alias for this: https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html

Make sure you use absolute path to python and `fix_newline.py` on your machine:

```
alias fix_newline='/path/to/your/python /path/to/fix_newline.py'
```

Then you can use with:

```
fix_newline file.txt
```

If you want this alias to be permanent make sure to put this configuration in you `~/.bashrc` file: https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/sample-bashrc.html

Comment: Please don't link to the ABS -- the freenode #bash channel denizens wrote the [BashGuide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CommandsAndArguments#Aliases) because we were tired of needing to teach people to unlearn bad habits they picked up there. Also consider the [official manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html) as a canonical source that's reliably updated whenever bash is.

Comment: (Also, `black`, `pip`, etc. which the OP wants to emulate aren't aliases at all)

Comment: ...that's important, because `~/.bashrc` isn't run by noninteractive shells, so if your editor or another C executable runs a shell command, it won't see aliases, so it won't be able to find the desired tool. (And even if it _does_ read `.bashrc`, aliases are turned off by default in noninteractive shells!)