# How to create Azure Databricks jobs of type python wheel by terraform

Tags: terraform, databricks, azure-databricks, terraform-provider-databricks, databricks-workflows

I am using terraform to implement a databricks job in Azure. I have a python wheel that I need to execute in this job. Following terraform Azure databricks documentation at [this link](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/job) I know how to implement a databricks notebook job. However, what I need is a **databricks job** of **type "python wheel"**. All the examples provided in the mentioned link are to create databricks jobs of either type "notebook_task", or "spark_jar_task" or "pipeline_task". None of them is what I exactly need. If you look into databricks workspace however, you can see there is a specific job of type "python wheel". Below you can see this in the workspace:

[image]

Just to elaborate more, according to documentation I have already created a job. Following is my main.tf file:

```
resource "databricks_notebook" "this" {
  path     = "/Users/myusername/${var.notebook_subdirectory}/${var.notebook_filename}"
  language = var.notebook_language
  source   = "./${var.notebook_filename}"
}

resource "databricks_job" "sample-tf-job" {
  name = var.job_name
  existing_cluster_id = "0342-285291-x0vbdshv"  ## databricks_cluster.this.cluster_id
  notebook_task {
    notebook_path = databricks_notebook.this.path 
  }
}
```

**As I said, this job is of type "Notebook" which is also in screen shot. The job I need is of type "Python wheel".**

I am pretty sure terraform has already provided the capability to create "Python wheel" jobs as by looking at the source code in [terraform provider for databricks](https://github.com/databricks/terraform-provider-databricks/blob/master/jobs/resource_job.go) I can see at currently line 49 python wheel task is defined. However, it is not clear to me how to call it in my code. Below is the source code I am referring to:

```
// PythonWheelTask contains the information for python wheel jobs
type PythonWheelTask struct {
    EntryPoint      string            `json:"entry_point,omitempty"`
    PackageName     string            `json:"package_name,omitempty"`
    Parameters      []string          `json:"parameters,omitempty"`
    NamedParameters map[string]string `json:"named_parameters,omitempty"`
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `notebook_task` you just need to use the `python_wheel_task` configuration block, as described in the [provider documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/job#python_wheel_task-configuration-block). Something like this:

```
resource "databricks_job" "sample-tf-job" {
  name = var.job_name

  task {
    task_key = "a"
    existing_cluster_id = "0342-285291-x0vbdshv"  ## databricks_cluster.this.cluster_id
    python_wheel_task {
      package_name = "my_package"
      entry_point = "entry_point"
    }
    library {
      whl = "dbfs:/FileStore/baz.whl"
    } 
  }
}
```

P.S. It's better not to use interactive clusters as it's more expensive

Comment: It worked, but what can I use for Entrypoint? I have all my code in __init__.py in a while loop, without having any functions. Is __init__.py the entry point?

Comment: it depends on how you packaged the wheel. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774824/explain-python-entry-points