# How to create Azure Databricks job of type python wheel by using Azure databricks API

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-workflows, databricks-rest-api

I would like to **create a databricks job of type "python wheel"** in Azure by using **databricks API**. I have a python wheel that I need to execute in this job.

This question is related to my other question at [this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75579462/how-to-create-azure-databricks-jobs-of-type-python-wheel-by-terraform), just the technology used to implement this has changed.

Following the [Azure databricks API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs) I know how to create a databricks job that can execute a notebook. However, what I need is a **databricks job** of **type "python wheel"**.
All my code is implemented in a python wheel and it needs to run 24/7. According to the requirements that I got from the development team, they need to have a job of type "python wheel" and not "notebook".

As you see [databricks documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/workflows/jobs/how-to-use-python-wheels-in-workflows.html) already shows how a job of type python wheel can be created from the databricks workspace. I, however, need to automate this process in a DevOps pipeline, that's why I would like to do it by making API call to databricks API. Below is the code I have implemented to created a databricks job. This code is using a notebook to execute the code. As I mentioned I need to run a "python wheel" job just as it is explained [here](https://docs.databricks.com/workflows/jobs/how-to-use-python-wheels-in-workflows.html). Below you can see this type of job in the workspace:

[image: Databricks job of type python wheel]

My current code is as below: **My objective is to change it to run a python wheel instead of a notebook**:

```
import requests
import os


# both 2.0 and 2.1 API can create job.
dbrks_create_job_url = "https://"+os.environ['DBRKS_INSTANCE']+".azuredatabricks.net/api/2.1/jobs/create"

DBRKS_REQ_HEADERS = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + os.environ['DBRKS_BEARER_TOKEN'],
    'X-Databricks-Azure-Workspace-Resource-Id': '/subscriptions/'+ os.environ['DBRKS_SUBSCRIPTION_ID'] +'/resourceGroups/'+ os.environ['DBRKS_RESOURCE_GROUP'] +'/providers/Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces/' + os.environ['DBRKS_WORKSPACE_NAME'],
    'X-Databricks-Azure-SP-Management-Token': os.environ['DBRKS_MANAGEMENT_TOKEN']}

CLUSTER_ID = "\"" + os.environ["DBRKS_CLUSTER_ID"] + "\""
NOTEBOOK_LOCATION = "\"" + os.environ["NOTEBOOK_LOCATION"] + "test-notebook" + "\""
print("Notebook path is {}".format(NOTEBOOK_LOCATION))
print(CLUSTER_ID)

body_json = """
    {
    "name": "A sample job to trigger from DevOps",
    "tasks": [
        {
        "task_key": "ExecuteNotebook",
        "description": "Execute uploaded notebook including tests",
        "depends_on": [],
        "existing_cluster_id": """ + CLUSTER_ID + """,
        "notebook_task": {
          "notebook_path": """ + NOTEBOOK_LOCATION + """,
          "base_parameters": {}
        },
        "timeout_seconds": 300,
        "max_retries": 1,
        "min_retry_interval_millis": 5000,
        "retry_on_timeout": false
      }
],
    "email_notifications": {},
    "name": "Run_Unit_Tests",
    "max_concurrent_runs": 1}
"""

print("Request body in json format:")
print(body_json)

response = requests.post(dbrks_create_job_url, headers=DBRKS_REQ_HEADERS, data=body_json) 

if response.status_code == 200:
    print("Job created successfully!")
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.content)
    print("Job Id = {}".format(response.json()['job_id']))
    print("##vso[task.setvariable variable=DBRKS_JOB_ID;isOutput=true;]{b}".format(b=response.json()['job_id'])) 
else:
    print("job failed!")
    raise Exception(response.content)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's simple - instead of `notebook_task` you just need to use `python_wheel_task` as it's described in the REST API docs. And you need to provide `package_name` and `entry_point` parameters inside the JSON object.

And don't forget to add the wheel file in the `libraries` block.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on that a little? By API docs are you refering to here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs I looked into swagger file and it has not provided any examples of python_wheel_task. They are all of type spark_jar_task.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned by @Alex Ott, instead of using the `notebook_task` you need to use `pyhton_wheel_task`.

Based on the [Job API 2.1 docs](https://redocly.github.io/redoc/?url=https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/databricks/_extras/api-refs/jobs-2.1-azure.yaml).

Comment: [Do not include pictures of text in your questions or answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557).